# Tensorflow: can not obtain same result mini-batch SGD optimizer compared to Kaldi nnet1

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build a Tensorflow example with a simple multl-layer 
perceptron (MLP) functionality with one hidden layer. However, when I tested it and compared to other software e.g. Kaldi nnet1, the convergence during the training is not efficient, or cannot be comparable to Kaldi nnet1. I tried my best to make all the parameters the same (input, int target, batch size, learning rate, etc.), however, still confused where could be the reasons. Some pieces of codes are as follows:

```
Initialization:
self.weight = [tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([440, 8192],stddev=0.1))]
self.bias   = [tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape=8192))]
self.weight.append( tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([8192, 8],stddev=0.1)) )
self.bias.append( tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape=8)) )
self.act = [tf.nn.sigmoid( tf.matmul(self.input, self.weight[0]) + self.bias[0] )]
self.nn_out =  tf.matmul(self.act, self.weight[1]) + self.bias[1]) 
self.nn_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(self.nn_out)
self.nn_tgt = tf.placeholder("int64", shape=[None,])
self.cost_mean = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(self.nn_out, self.nn_tgt))
self.train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learn_rate).minimize(self.cost_mean)
# saver 
self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
self.sess = tf.Session()
self.sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
Training:
for epoch in xrange(20):
        feats_tr, tgts_tr = shuffle(feats_tr, tgts_tr, random_state=777)
        # restore the exisiting model
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(ckpt_dir)
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            self.load(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)               
        # mini-batch
        tr_loss = []
        for idx_begin in range(0,len(feats_tr), 512):
            idx_end = idx_begin + batch_size
            batch_feats, batch_tgts = feats_tr[idx_begin:idx_end],tgts_tr[idx_begin:idx_end]
            _, loss_val = self.sess.run([self.train_step, self.cost_mean], feed_dict = {self.nn_in: batch_feats,
self.nn_tgt: batch_tgts,self.learn_rate: learn_rate})                                       
            tr_loss.append(loss_val)
# cross-validation
cv_loss = []
    for idx_begin in range(0,len(feats_cv), 512):
        idx_end = idx_begin + batch_size
        batch_feats, batch_tgts = feats[idx_begin:idx_end],tgts[idx_begin:idx_end]
        loss_all.append(self.sess.run(self.cost_mean, 
                                        feed_dict = {   self.nn_in: batch_feats,
                                                        self.nn_tgt: batch_tgts}))
print(  "Avg Loss for Training: "+str(np.mean(tr_loss)) + \
                    " Avg Loss for Validation: "+str(np.mean(cv_loss)) )
# save model per epoch if np.mean(cv_loss) less than previous
if (epoch+1)%1==0:
    if loss_new < loss:
        loss = loss_new
        print( "Model accepted in epoch %d" %(epoch+1) )
        # save model to ckpt_dir with mdl_nam
        self.saver.save(self.sess, mdl_nam, global_step=epoch+1)
    else:
        print( "Model rejected in epoch %d" %(epoch+1) )
```

and I generated a simple annealing learning rate control as: if the average of cross-validation loss is not improved by a certain threshold, then halving the 'learn_late' with initial 0.008.

I checked all the parameters when compared to Kaldi nnet1, and the only difference now is the initialization parameters of weights and biases. I am not sure whether initialization will affect too much. However, the convergence in terms of 'cv_loss' during training in Tensorflow (Avg. CV Loss 1.99) is not good as Kaldi nnet1 (Avg. CV Loss 0.95). Can someone help to point out where I did something wrong or I missed something? 
Many thanks in advance !!!

Comment: It seems you are not using any variable in your code

Comment: sorry, some copy-paste typo, the weights and biases are: self.weight = [tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([440, 8192],stddev=0.1))] and self.bias = [tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape=8192))], and also for the latter append. I re-edited the above codes. The convergence differences still exist, other suggestions to check?

Comment: any more suggestions to check where the problems are??? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At each epoch, you call `self.load(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)` which seems to load previously saved weights.

Your model cannot learn if it is reset to the initial weights at each epoch.

Comment: thanks Olivier! when the previous saved model is called, then the next epoch is based on this saved model to further train the model, which is not the case the weights are still initial ones, right? my purpose of self.load(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path) is to load the previous good model for further training at next epoch, or my codes are wrong for such purpose?

Comment: Normally here it what you should do: 1. load the model, 2. train during multiple epochs, and regularly save the model, 3. test. Your code gives me the impression that you load multiple times the same model weights, without saving them at the end of each epoch. You could maybe clarify your code

Comment: sorry for confusion! the model is saved each epoch when np.mean(cv_loss) is less than previous cv_loss. hence, the load() loads the previous best model before the next epoch starts. what I worried about is that each time when the model is loaded, the weights and biases are not updated for sess.run(), but it could not be when I saved the model each epoch.

Comment: In general, you should not load any weight during training (only save them to have checkpoints). I don't see in your code when you save weights during training, can you have better indentation?

Comment: I added the save codes above, please check. I guess when self.saver.save(self.sess, mdl_nam, global_step=epoch+1), the model parameters (weights and biases) will be saved, right?

Comment: You don't need to reload weights each epoch, so remove any code loading your weights during training. A good thing to try is to **overfit** a small training set (like 50 images). Try it and tell me if you succeed

Comment: A good learning rate to start with is 0.01 or 0.001. You can stick with it until you see no improvement and then divide it by 10. Having a linear decay is also good, but you have to choose the total number of epochs you want to do (100-200 is enough)

Comment: I tried the simple MNIST data and SGD works with 98% accuracy with learning rate starting with 1.0 and a smoothing decreasing. when a small learning rate e.g. 0.08 is used, SGD is doomed. it seems that SGD is very sensitive to the learning rate, and I am a bit confused how to properly choose a right learning rate. the default learning rate in Kaldi nnet1 is 0.008, and is it a good one for Tensorflow SGD?

Comment: Tensorflow SGD works, however, it seems that it does not work as Kaldi nnet1 does, which confuses me a lot! Actually it shall not have too many tricks inside this SGD algorithm. any more suggestions to check the differences?

Comment: SGD will work the same in every framework, so the difference should not be there.

Comment: I agree~ I also tried Adam optimizer (lr=0.01), and the results are still not reasonable. hmmm, probably some places before training are wrong with my codes. anyway, thanks a lot Olivier!!!